# Using gatling session variable in triple qouted string

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

How to use session variable in StringBody of gatling?

I have defined my `exec` like,

```
val migrateAsset = exec(_.set("assetId", AssetIdGenerator.generateRandomAssetId()))
      .exec(http("Migrate Asset")
      .post(s"$url/asset/metadata")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("Authorization", s"Bearer ${authToken}")
      .body(StringBody(
          s"""
            |{
            |    "objectType" : "DocumentType",
            |    "fileName" : "main.xml",
            |    "locations" : [
            |        {
            |            "region" : "eu-west-1",
            |            "url" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/${bucketName}/${assetId}"
            |        },
            |        {
            |            "region" : "us-east-1",
            |            "url" : s"https://s3.amazonaws.com/${bucketName}/${assetId}"
            |        }
            |    ],
            |    "format" : "MAIN",
            |    "mimeType" : "text/plain"
            |}
          """.stripMargin
      ))
      .check(status.is(200)))
```

In the body, I want same `assetId` to be passed for both eu-west and us-east regions. Since, assetId is randomly generated, I have stored it in session variable so as to make sure, I use same assetId for both locations.

But I cant pass `assetId` in StringBody format. It keeps giving me error like,

> AssetsMigrationLoadSimulation.scala:31: not found: value
>   assetId
>               |            "url" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/${bucketName}/${assetId}"

Comment: Have you tried using an expression function like this: `.body(StringBody(session => """{ "myContent": """" + someGenerator(session) + """" }""")).asJSON` from the [docs](http://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#http-request-body)

Comment: Not quite sure, but you've got a lot of s"..." in there. This means Scala will evaluate the EL constructs itself, and not Gatling. If you remove the s prefix, it might work.

Answer (score 4):

As Hans-Peter mentioned - your IDE has seen the ${...} that you're using to reference a gatling session parameter and decided that you are trying to do regular scala string interpolation - so it's put the 's' in front of the string.

remove the 's' and this should work